# Laravel: Querying to check object field?

Tags: php, laravel

I am expanding on a query and I want to check the `Order` table further.  There is a field called `detail` and it is empty most of the time but for special orders, it gets populated with `{special_order: true}`.  I want to exclude those from the query.  How would I use the `->where` to exclude these?

```
Order::where('status', '!=', Order::COMPLETE)
      ->where('finished', '=', '0')
```

EDIT: I tried adding: `->whereNot('details->special_order', 'true')`

Comment: So what did you try ?

Comment: Do you mean that this column contains JSON?

Comment: yes, sorry -- I will edit the question now to show what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried adding: `->whereNot('details->special_order', 'true')`

`whereNot()` doesn't exist.

[As the documentation states](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#json-where-clauses), you can use the common `where()` clause, as this can also be applied to JSON columns:

```
$results = Order::query()
              ->where('status', '!=', Order::COMPLETE)
              ->where('details->special_order', '=', false) // <---
              ->get();
```

PD: I've test it myself to confirm, and it works. Also, this will not throw an error if some of your records have the `details` column empty.